# How do I pass functions from the service to the controller and call it there Angularjs syntax es6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I try to call getTodos functions in the controller, it does not return any value. I want to assign to `this.todos` the value returned by the `getTodos()` function. `this.todos` return null

```
/* ----- todo/todo.service.js ----- */
   class TodosController {
   constructor(TodoService) {
    'ngInject'
    this.ArtistsListService = ArtistsListService;
   }

    $onInit() {
      this.todos = null;
      this.TodoServiceService.getTodos().then(response => 
 this.todos = response);
      console.log(this.todos);
    }
}

export default TodosController;`
```

---

```
/* ----- todo/todo.service.js ----- */
   export class TodoService {
  constructor($http) {
    'ngInject';
    this.$http = $http;
  }
  getTodos() {
    return this.$http.get('/api/todos').then(response => 
 response.data);
  }
}
```

---

```
/* ----- todo/todo.module.js ----- */
 import angular from 'angular';
 import { TodoComponent } from './todo.component';
  import { TodoService } from './todo.service';
 import './todo.scss';

 export const TodoModule = angular
  .module('todo', [])
  .component('todo', TodoComponent)
  .service('TodoService', TodoService)
  .name;
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
export class TodoService {
  constructor($http) {
    'ngInject';
    this.$http = $http;
  }
  getTodos() {
    return this.$http.get('/api/todos');
  }
}
```

and in controller:

```
   class TodosController {
   constructor(TodoService) {
    'ngInject'
    this.ArtistsListService = ArtistsListService;
   }

    $onInit() {
      this.todos = null;
      this.TodoServiceService.getTodos().then(response => 
        {
           this.todos = response.data;
           console.log(this.todos);
        },
        (error) => { console.error(error) }
       );

    }
}

export default TodosController;
```

You need to return `http` promise  as

`return this.$http.get('/api/todos')`

in the service file to get it a promise

Comment: Can I also use `.catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })`  ?

Comment: @Umbro : Try ` (error) => { console.error(error) }` as I have written in my updated answer. i